# Creating non-traditional shape tooltip in android with border

Tags: android, xml, styles, shapes

Hello fellow Android designers,

I am struggling right now to create xml tooltip that would look like the one on this picture:

[image: preview]

Unfortunately it seems like a hell of a work. Till now I was only able to create a simple rounded rectangle like that:

[image: preview 2]

Is it actually possible to create such a shape I have presented on the first photo using xml styling or should I try to create it programatically (which will probably take huge amount of time and creating border would be really hard)? Or maybe the simplest solution is the best and I should use partially transparent png image with the shape of my choosing?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time looking. Custom shapes in xml are not possible in the standard API.

Comment: @anthropomo: how about styling them with shape.xml / styles.xml? It's probably for simple shapes right?

Comment: Yes, oval, rectangle and line. I've done trapezoids in code and it is barely worth it.

Comment: Looks like 9-patch drawable is a way to go as Axarydax suggested (and even easy one). Thanks for your help though @anthropomo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw it using [stretchable 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) drawable.

You can specify there which parts are fixed (the little knob on the left and corners) and which are stretchable (all other parts)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Axarydax. Will definately give it a try. One more question... Should I set fixed part on borders too?

Comment: Done simple testing and it worked. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!